# php & wordpress - show full image instead of thumbnail?

Tags: php, image, wordpress, thumbnails

I'm using this to show images on my wordpress blog-

functions:

```
add_theme_support( 'post-thumbnails' );  
set_post_thumbnail_size( 590, 275, true ); // 590 pixels wide by 275 pixels tall, hard crop mode
```

index:

```
<div class="post-wrap">
      <?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?>
      <?php the_excerpt(__('keep reading', 'grisaille')); ?></div>
      <?php wp_link_pages(
                array(  'before'           => '<p class="pages-links">' . __('Pages:', 'grisaille'),
                        'after'            => '</p>',
                        'next_or_number'   => 'number',
                        'nextpagelink'     => __('Next page', 'grisaille'),
                        'previouspagelink' => __('Previous page', 'grisaille'),
                        'pagelink'         => '%')); ?>
      <p class="postMeta"><small><?php _e('Category', 'grisaille'); ?> <?php the_category(', ') ?> | <?php _e('Tags', 'grisaille'); ?>: <?php the_tags(' '); ?></small></p>

      <hr class="noCss" />
    </li>

    <?php comments_template(); // Get wp-comments.php template ?>

    <?php endwhile; ?>
```

Instead of showing thumbnails, I'd like to show full images. How do I accomplish this?

Comment: it's wordpress, not PHP!

Comment: @YourCommonSense  Wordpress doesn't have it's unique code, it's still php..

Comment: Okay, -1 for lacking the logic. the functions you are using are wordpress. PHP has nothing to do with them and PHP knowledge won't help with them.

Comment: ah forget it and focus on the question

Comment: This question is 100% WordPress-specific, and would be a better fit for WPSE.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Replace this:

```
 <?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?>
```

...with this:

```
 <?php the_post_thumbnail( 'full' ); ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use this function:

```
wp_get_attachment_image(get_post_thumbnail_id(get_post(get_the_ID()),'full',0,array('title' => '' ));
```

[Check this link](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_attachment_image)

Comment: that seems to be what i'm looking for, but in what context am i to use it? i've substituted the function you gave for `<?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?>` and also used the example given in the codex, but it doesn't seem to work..

Comment: oh sorry the function `get_page_by_title` will not do the give thing. please check the edit

Comment: check it and tell me if it does not works. I will reply later when i get time

Comment: in what context is this used?

Answer (score 1):

There are four valid sizes built in to the WordPress core.

```
the_post_thumbnail('thumbnail');       // Thumbnail (default 150px x 150px max)
the_post_thumbnail('medium');          // Medium resolution (default 300px x 300px max)
the_post_thumbnail('large');           // Large resolution (default 640px x 640px max)
the_post_thumbnail('full');            // Original image resolution (unmodified)
```

The last is one you're looking for.